# Is it possible to extend pydantic models generated using datamodel-code-generator?

Tags: python, pydantic

I am using the [datamodel-code-generator](https://koxudaxi.github.io/datamodel-code-generator/) to generate [pydantic models](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/) from a JSON schema.

Here is the [JSON schema](https://gist.github.com/alexandredias3d/16efbced3efc90a8e889b176a6b0ae12) used.

And the generated models after running the datamodel-code-generator.

```py
# File: datamodel.py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Record(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str

class Table(BaseModel):
    records: List[Record]

class Globals(BaseModel):
    table: Table
```

I've been trying to extend the generated classes with new attributes.

```py
# File: extensions.py
import json
from datamodel import Table, Globals

class ExtendedTable(Table):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('ExtendedTable Constructor')

        # Won't work because "ExtendedTable" object has no field "records_by_id"
        self.records_by_id = {record.id: record for record in self.records}

class ExtendedGlobals(Globals):
    def __init__(self, table: ExtendedTable):
        super().__init__(table=table)
        print('ExtendedGlobals Constructor')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    records = '''
    {
        "table": {
            "records": [{"id": 0, "name": "A"}, {"id": 1, "name": "B"}]
        }
    }
    '''

    content = json.loads(records)

    # Both won't call ExtendedTable.__init__()
    ExtendedGlobals(**content)
    ExtendedGlobals.parse_obj(content)

    ExtendedGlobals(table=ExtendedTable(**content['table']))
```

However, I haven't found a way to make the Globals class use the extended definition of the table.
Also, simply adding new fields to the subclass does not seem to work.

Is there a way to extend these classes without having to modify the pydantic generated models? Or maybe another tool to generate Python code from JSON schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I haven't found a way to make the Globals class use the extended definition of the table

You can change the type of a field in a subclass if you declare the field again using the desired type.

> Also, simply adding new fields to the subclass does not seem to work

It looks like you are setting instance attributes in the `__init__()` method, but fields are declared as class attributes.

This example shows a way to add a calculated field `records_by_id`  to `ExtendedTable` and use `ExtendedTable` in `ExtendedGlobals`:

```python
# File: extensions.py
import json
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Optional

from pydantic import Field, validator

from datamodel import Globals, Record, Table


class ExtendedTable(Table):
    # New fields are declared as class attributes not as instance attributes inside the __init__()
    # Calculated fields usually have a default value or default factory so that you don't have to provide a value
    # I prefer a default_factory for mutable values
    records_by_id: Dict[int, Record] = Field(default_factory=dict)

    # A validator can populate a calculated field
    # Use always=True to run the validator even if a value is not supplied and the default value is used
    @validator("records_by_id", always=True)
    def _calculate_records_by_id(
        cls, value: Dict[int, Record], values: Dict[str, Any]
    ) -> Dict[int, Record]:
        records: Optional[List[Record]] = values.get("records")
        if records is None:
            # The records field was not valid
            # Return value or raise a ValueError instead if you want
            return value
        return {record.id: record for record in records}


class ExtendedGlobals(Globals):
    # You can change the type of a field in a subclass if you declare the field again
    table: ExtendedTable


if __name__ == "__main__":
    records = """
    {
        "table": {
            "records": [{"id": 0, "name": "A"}, {"id": 1, "name": "B"}]
        }
    }
    """

    content = json.loads(records)
    extended_globals = ExtendedGlobals.parse_obj(content)
    print(repr(extended_globals))
```

Output:

```
ExtendedGlobals(table=ExtendedTable(records=[Record(id=0, name='A'), Record(id=1, name='B')], records_by_id={0: Record(id=0, name='A'), 1: Record(id=1, name='B')}))
```